# pyspark "isin" taking too long

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of ID's which needs to be filtered from a pyspark.sql.DataFrame.
The ID has 3000000 values. The approach I am using is

```
df_tmp.filter(fn.col("device_id").isin(device_id))
```

This is taking very long and getting stuck.
What is an alternate for this?

Comment: What is the size of your `df_tmp` and `device_id`?

Comment: maybe create a dataframe for `device_id` and do an inner join?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_temp.join(
    F.broadcast(
        spark.createDataFrame(
            [(ID_,) for ID_ in device_id],
            ["device_id"],
        )
    ),
    on="device_id",
)
```

Comment: try with and without the broadcast ... 3'000'000 with only ids is not that big so broadcast should do its magic.

Comment: Brilliant! Reduced by runtime from 40 mins to 15 mins.